# Detect cached response in Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, caching, swift2, alamofire

The app I'm currently working on needs to present a notification to the user only when a networking request returns a non-cached response.

The app uses Alamofire for networking requests.

How can I determine if a response from Alamofire came from the cache or not?

Answer (score 2):

the only way is to check [HTTP header fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) in HTTP response. Cache-Control field tells all caching mechanisms from server to client whether they may cache this object. It is measured in seconds. **Cache-Control: max-age=3600** means that the content of respond can be one hour old.

if you need non cached respond from server, you have to specify Cache-Control field in your request as **Cache-Control: no-cache**

there is no difference if you are using Alamofire or not